# convert an IP address into a string python

Tags: python, pandas, string, list, pandasql

I have the following df and i would like to convert each ip address into a string i.e. "207.46.13.187"

I have tried the following, but it didn't work. I am not sure if the decimals have anything to do with it.

```
df['IP'] = df['IP'].astype(str)
```

current dataframe:

```
    IP            date  year   month
0   207.46.13.187   24  2020    6
1   207.46.13.187   24  2020    6
2   40.77.167.144   24  2020    6
3   40.77.167.144   24  2020    6
4   207.46.13.146   23  2020    6
... ... ... ... ...
4512    82.145.221.171  14  2015    5
4513    82.145.209.120  13  2015    5
4514    82.145.221.232  13  2015    5
4515    82.145.221.232  13  2015    5
4516    82.145.222.238  13  2015    5
```

Goal:

```
       IP          date year   month
0   "207.46.13.187" 24  2020    6
1   "207.46.13.187" 24  2020    6
2   "40.77.167.144" 24  2020    6
3   "40.77.167.144" 24  2020    6
4   "207.46.13.146" 23  2020    6
```

Thank you!

Comment: What is the type of your input ?

Comment: please add the `pandas` tag to your question, and in order to best help provide input and expected output data.

Comment: Looks stringy to me

Comment: Ditto @Chris. AFAIK Pandas doesn't even *have* an IP dtype, you'd need to use [cyberpandas](https://cyberpandas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to even have the opportunity of an IP dtype.

Comment: @Kenia Cevallos so you want to add quotes to your string that's already a string?

Comment: its an object, I am new to python. the goal is to run the column into a function (but it has to be a string) to create a new column indicating the country the ip address is from.

Comment: Isn't your IP column already a string? looks like it.

Comment: If its dtype is "object", then it is a string!

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
df['IP'] = df['IP'].apply(lambda x: str(x))
```

Below is a quick example I have compiled. I will be looking at whole integers only, but hopefully this clarifies some confusion with data types in Pandas.

I will create a dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'IP': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]})
```

Let's check the type, it should return integers:

```
df.dtypes

IP    int64
dtype: object
```

Let's check this with a list

```
df['IP'].values.tolist()
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5] # we have a list of integers!
```

Now, let's convert it to a string:

```
df['IP'] = df['IP'].apply(lambda x: str(x))
```

Let's check the type again, it should return **object**:

```
df.dtypes

IP    object
dtype: object
```

Let's check this with a list again:

```
df['IP'].values.tolist()
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
```